# catalog_category_product_index table empty (Magento 2.2.5)

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, magento-2.2.5, index

Our indexer re-fills the table `catalog_category_product_index_store1`, but the table `catalog_category_product_index` remains empty.

I have found this issue https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/991 , but even after an upgrade of the smile/elasticsuite module to 2.5.13, the table remains empty.

In some of our development environments, the table is filled. But when I truncate it and reindex, it stays empty.

This is how I reindex:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table `catalog_category_product_index` is not updated anymore since Magento 2.2.

Records might be left in the table, but the reindexing neither truncates nor fills it.